# How do I copy resources to webapp directory using Maven and Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

I'm following an old example on Jetty:
[Quick Start - Servlets and .jsp pages (hosted within the same .jar as the embedder](https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty)

It's showing me how to serve up resource files from the web app directory.

The absolute path at run time appears to be:

```
C:\Projects\appname\target\classes\com\companyname\product\webapp
```

I'd like to keep the source in another location, perhaps:

```
C:\Projects\appname\resources
```

I'm using maven, and do most of my development in Eclipse.  What is the best practice for how to set this up?  Should I use a maven plugin to copy the resources to the output directory at build time?  Are my project source and output folders set up to any recognizable practice?

I've just set up things so that they run so far, I'm open to suggestions on improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try follow maven directory layout:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

```
C:\Projects\appname\src\main\webapp
C:\Projects\appname\src\main\java
C:\Projects\appname\src\main\resources
C:\Projects\appname\pom.xml
```

If you are using eclipse kepler, enable maven nature on your project. Then go to "Server" and add a jetty server. And to run your project, simply click "Run As" -> "Run on Server".